# Phones dialing wrong number from tel-hyperlink

Tags: mobile, tel

We received a complaint that some visitors to our website are dialing the wrong number to get in contact with us.

Our website has a hyperlink in the following form in the footer:

```
Call us at <a href="tel:+4712345678">12345678</a>
```

Note that the "+47" (international code) is NOT displayed visually, it is only included in the hyperlink. But now it turns out a limited number of people (circa one a day) is actually calling a private local number at **47123456**. Not many considering the size of our business, but still a major nuisance for the family receiving these calls.

The people calling say they just pressed the link to dial.

Has anybody else had these problems? Is anybody aware of mobile phones that do not properly support the tel hyperlink? Any suggestions for a solution? (Apart from changing our or their phone number, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways smart phones pick a telephone number.
some are reading the text of your website - some use the  tag

on my first try: I would add the +47 to the displayed telephone number
on my second try (or both together): I  would replace +47 with 0047 (its norway - or?)

and before posting i got a third idea: which encoding has the webserver and which encoding has the html / PHP page in sourcecode? Both UTF-8 or something else?
Maybe your server is sending it in a different way than the website is created and somehow some smartphones can't handle it correctly.

Comment: I recommend to replace the +47 with 0047 as well.

Comment: The encoding should not be a problem, both the page template (an XSLT file), the server setting, and the HTML output are UTF-8.

I will try replacing it with 0047 (yeah, it's Norway). It's too bad that not every country uses 00 as international access code. USA is using 011 if I'm not mistaken, and Finland (our neighbor country) uses 09x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is pretty simple: this is the URL-Encoding.

The + char is an reserved character within the URL and represents an space.

To get an actual + sign replace it with the URL encoded version: %2B

See Links for details:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

[W3Scools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Its not that simple.  The plus is mandated by the RFC.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943196/should-the-plus-in-tel-uris-be-encoded

Comment: While it's true that the RFC clearly states a literal "+" should be used, it may well be possible that some browsers have a bad implementation and are interpretating the "+" as a space character. Note that it's only a limited set of visitors that are dialing the wrong number, so it is not the most popular browsers that are making this mistake.