# Should the plus in tel URIs be encoded?

Tags: uri, tel

In a URI, spaces can be encoded as `+`.  Since this is the case, should the leading plus be encoded when creating tel URIs with international prefix?

Which is better?  Do both work in practice?

```
<a href="tel:+1234">Call me</a>
<a href="tel:%2B1234">Call me</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

From [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-3) of RFC 3966 (*The tel URI for Telephone Numbers*):

> If the reserved characters "+", ";", "=", and "?" are used as delimiters between components of the "tel" URI, they MUST NOT be percent encoded.

You would only percent-encode a `+` if it’s part of a parameter value:

> These characters ["+", ";", "=", and "?"] MUST be percent encoded if they appear in tel URI parameter values.

---

I’m not sure if the leading `+`, which indicates that it’s a [global number](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.1.4), counts as delimiter, but the definition of a global number says:

> Globally unique numbers are identified by the leading "+" character.

So it refers to `+`, not to something percent-encoded.

And also the [examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-6) make clear that it’s not supposed to be percent-encoded, e.g.:

> ```
> tel:+1-201-555-0123
> ```

---

Note that spaces in `tel` URIs (e.g., in parameter values) may not be encoded with a `+`. Using `+` instead of `%20` for a space character is not something that may be done in any URI; it’s only possible in URIs whose URI scheme explicitly defines that.

Answer (score 2):

The tel: URI scheme doesn't have a provision for encoding spaces - see [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966):

```
    5.1.1.  Separators in Phone Numbers

    ...

    even though ITU-T E.123 [E.123] recommends the use of space
       characters as visual separators in printed telephone numbers, "tel"
       URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators to avoid excessive
       escaping.
```

The plus sign encodes a space specifically only in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default content type for form submission - see [W3C info re: forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)). There's no valid way to encode a space in tel: URIs. See again RFC 3966 (page 5) for valid visual separators.