# Flask: How can I send '+' symbol into a GET query parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I'm using this code to get a query parameter, that is a 10 digit number that includes a '+' in the begin (it's a phone number, i.e. +541143214321). I can get the number ok, but it comes with and empty space instead of the '+'.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Run_Test(Resource):
    def get(self, enviro):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('phone_number', type=str, required=False)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        phone_number = args['phone_number']
        print("phone_number: ", phone_number, flush=True)


def start():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 9090
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=True)


api.add_resource(Run_Test, '/run-test/<enviro>')
```

The request I run is, from Postman: 
`GET http://localhost:9090/run-test/pre?phone_number='+541143214321'`

The result I get:
phone_number: ' 541143214321'

The same with '', with "" and without them. Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should the plus in tel URIs be encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943196/should-the-plus-in-tel-uris-be-encoded)

Comment: Encode it: `phone_number=%2B541143214321`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. In that case I prefer ask the user to don't send the '+' and then I can add it in the backend. The ideal is to send the phone number with the '+' in the request because we use it, in that way, in other external APIs. Do you think would be another way to add the '+' literally?

Comment: Your _users_ don't have to encode it. This is just regular URI encoding. If you're generating the requests in JavaScript use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`, e.g. `encodeURIComponent("+11234567890")` → `"%2B11234567890"`. If you're doing it in Python, use `urllib.parse.urlencode()`, e.g. `urllib.parse.urlencode({"phone_number": "+11234567890"})`.

Comment: But the users generate the request, through Postman or Curl command. I'm configuring the API in backend to receive the requests and process it.

Comment: Your actual end users are using Postman and curl as their interface? I'd expect Postman to do the encoding properly out of the box, but curl won't. Are your Postman users putting the query parameter in as an actual query parameter, or modifying the URL manually?

Comment: Yes, generally Postman, they are users of my team (it is an internal tool). In Postman they write, i.e. '?phone_number=+541143214321' at the end of URL. I tried with this, as commented before, but the '+' don't come. Or, at least, I don't see it when I use print() to console.

Comment: Right, but that's typing that at the end of the URL. [Add it as a parameter instead](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-parameters). If that doesn't work I'll be surprised.

Comment: Ok, regarding I see there, Postman don't encoded automatically that chars. Clicking over the '+' to ask for the Encode, it works adding there '%2B'. If there isn't other option, I would be a solution. Thanks @Chris.